# Existence of extreme point in closed unit ball of normed space

Tags: functional-analysis

I just read the following quote from Conway:

> If $X$ is a Banach space, then $\text{ball }X^*$ is weak* compact, by Alaoglu's theorem. By the Krein-Milman Theorem, $\text{ball }X^*$ has many extreme points.

Where $\text{ball }X^*$ is the closed unit call in $X^*$. However, I don't understand why we need $X$ to be Banach here, since Alaoglu's theorem holds for normed spaces, and all assumptions make in Krein-Milman hold either way too. I've been thinking about this for an hour at this point and I just don't see it.

I would appreciate someone explaining why this does not hold for normed spaces. Thanks

Comment: It is true for any normed linear space.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Thanks for your response. I edited to include the full quote, can you comment on this too please? Maybe we need $X$ Banach for the second sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter. If $X$ is a normed space then the completion of $X$ say $V$ is a Banach space and $V^* = X^*. $ So w can always assume that $X$ is a Banach space.

Comment: Oke yes I see why we could start a proof of these statements by "wlog assume $X$ to be Banach", but we never once need to use this assumption right? Just find it weird to put it in the formulation then. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, you are right, thats it!